# No transactional EntityManager available;

Tags: spring, entitymanager

My app using spring and jpa, i have two config file:

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.api" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.api.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig { 
}
```

WebAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.webservice" })
  public static class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  }
```

Almost work fine, but sometime it throw an exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available` even I just select record (Not create, update or delete data.)

If I move annotation: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.api" })` to Class WebAppConfig and remove: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.webservice" })` then exception is disappear, but spring context load many time when server startup and spring beans are duplicate.

Or If I use `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class)` instead for `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` then exception also disappear.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ComponentScan on WebAppConfig and add the package in the ComponentScan annotation on AppConfig, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Could you then post your code, where you configure the EntityManager? Maybe there is an error in that.